# Why isn't my OneToMany List filled when persisting a JoinTable Object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm working on a hibernate project and there I have a @ManyToMany relationship between Car and CarDriver. The thing is that this relationship also has attributes, so therefore I make use of a seperate Entity which are connected to Car and CarDriver, this entity is called CarUsage.

My problem is that when I persist a CarUsage object, the lists of CarUsage in Car and CarDriver aren't filled with this new object.

This are my entities:

Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Car extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "registration_plate")
private String registrationPlate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="car")
private List<CarUsage> carUsages;

public String getRegistrationPlate() {
    return registrationPlate;
}

public void setRegistrationPlate(String registrationPlate) {
    this.registrationPlate = registrationPlate;
}

public List<CarUsage> getCarUsages() {
    return carUsages;
}

public void setCarUsages(List<CarUsage> carUsages) {
    this.carUsages = carUsages;
}
}
```

CarDriver

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car_driver")
public class CarDriver extends BaseEntity {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="carDriver")
private List<CarUsage> carUsages;

public List<CarUsage> getCarUsages() {
    return carUsages;
}

public void setCarUsages(List<CarUsage> carUsages) {
    this.carUsages = carUsages;
}
}
```

And my JoinTable CarUsage:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car_usage")
public class CarUsage extends BaseEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
private Car car;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "car_driver_id")
private CarDriver carDriver;
@Column(name = "start_date")
private Date startDate;
@Column(name = "end_date")
private Date endDate;
@Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
private boolean active;

public Car getCar() {
    return car;
}

public void setCar(Car car) {
    this.car = car;
}

public CarDriver getCarDriver() {
    return carDriver;
}

public void setCarDriver(CarDriver carDriver) {
    this.carDriver = carDriver;
}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
}
```

When I persist a new CarUsage, the lists in Car and CarDriver won't get updated.

```
CarUsage carUsage = carUsageCreator.makeCarUsage(companyCar, carDriver, new Date(), new Date(), true);
    carUsageDao.persist(carUsage);
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JPA/Hibernate Cascading :

Choose an owner side of the relation

Car > CarUsage > CarDriver or CarDriver > CarUsage > Car.

If CarDriver is the owner side, the mapping should be

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="carDriver",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<CarUsage> carUsages;
```

To create a new carUsage relation, you can create a method like this one :

```
public void driveCar(CarDriver carDriver, Car car){
    CarUsage carUsage = new CarUsage(carDriver, car, Date()....)
    carDriver.getCarUsages().add(carUsage);
    car.getCarUsages().add(carUsage);// Just to maintain coherence for the rest of the current transaction
      ...
}
```

If you are in transaction, this code will automatically persist carUsage instance. (No more carUsageDao.persist(carUsage) needed) ..

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do the job, guess I hoped hibernate would do everything for me and fill that list, but now i'll do it on another way myself. Thank you for the reply!